# JavaScript multiple condition filtering with array of conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a long array by which now i need to filter it based on users conditions:

My condition sample,

```
const filterCond = [{AC:'true'},{nonAC:'true'},{sleeper:'true'}];
```

And my array:

```
const array = [
   {
    "AC": "false",
    "nonAC": "true",
    "sleeper":"true",
    "availCatCard": "false",
   },
   {
    "AC": "true",
    "nonAC": "false",
    "sleeper":"false",
    "availCatCard": "false",
   },
   {
    "AC": "true",
    "nonAC": "true",
    "sleeper":"false",
    "availCatCard": "false",
   }
]
```

By this, I have multiple conditions;

1. Either AC or nonAC, but sometimes it can be only AC and it can be only nonAC
2. Sleeper & seater should be in or "||", sometimes it can be only Sleeper and it can be only seater

Like wise, the conditions goes on, so far now am using redux and so collecting user selected filters in an array and its "filterCond" (check above).

So far i have tried like this :

```
function filter(props){
    if( _.some(props, {AC:'true'}) && _.some(props, {nonAC:'true'}) === false )
      {
        return console.log(_.filter(array, {AC:'true'}).length)
      }
    else if( _.some(props, {nonAC:'true'}) && _.some(props, {AC:'true'}) === false )
      {
        return console.log(_.filter(array, {nonAC:'true'}).length)
      }
    else if( _.some(props, {AC:'true'}) === true && _.some(props, {AC:'true'}) === true )
      {
        return console.log(_.filter(array, function(data) {
            return data.AC === 'true' || data.nonAC === 'true';
        }).length)
      }
};

console.log(filter([{AC:'true'},{nonAC:'true'},{sleeper:'true'}]));
```

And when the conditions goes beyond the codes extends and for now am doing things for AC
& nonAC but how to perform that including sleeper :( totally confused

Comment: I feel like there's an intended question in there somewhere. What are you asking for? How to add additional filter criteria? Can you try expanding on your conditions? Can you also provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Am asking, how to handle these kind of various conditions. Is there any practice or should i need to put if else conditions for all condition's ? I dont know where to go from this point :(

Comment: In the past I've created an array of value/object - condition function pairs that is then reduced to a single boolean using array.prototype.some or array.prototype.every depending on if I need only a single condition to pass or if I need all conditions to pass.

Comment: Can you provide some example ? @DrewReese

Comment: is your condition like this? (AC == true or nonAC == true) and (sleeper == true or seater == true)?

Comment: yes also sometimes only AC === true and vice versa it can be both or it can be single !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a higher order filter function to handle applying filter conditions and is passed to your array.prototype.filter function.

```
const filterData = ({ filters = [], every = false }) => (el) =>
  filters[every ? "every" : "some"]((filterFn) => filterFn(el));
```

This consumes an options object that defines an array of filter condition functions that accept a single element value/object from your data array and returns the function used for the array filtering.

Example:

```
// AC AND nonAC
data.filter(filterData({
  filters: [
    ({ AC, nonAC }) => AC && nonAC,
  ],
}))
```

[image: Edit javascript-multiple-condition-filtering-with-array-of-conditions]

## Note

If your data is in the form

```
"AC": "false"
```

Where the booleans are stringified then make the following adjustment to your condition checkers, compare to `=== 'true'`:

```
({ AC, nonAC }) => AC === "true" || nonAC === "true"
```

## Edit

After discussion it seems some of these conditions are not mutually inclusive, or rather, they are only mutually inclusive in specific groups.

Still using a Higher Order Function, the logic is tweaked a bit to consume the array of key-value conditions.

Create a mapping function to map your user selected filters (`[{ AC: "true" }, ...]`) to a groups of "filterBy" values that are mutually inclusive. These will be logical OR'd (`||`) together while the sets will be exclusive by using logical AND'd (`&&`) together.

```
const mapfiltersToSets = (filters) => {
  const filtersObject = filters.reduce((conditions, condition) => {
    const [key, value] = Object.entries(condition).pop();

    switch (key) {
      case "AC":
      case "nonAC":
        return {
          ...conditions,
          acConditions: [...(conditions.acConditions || []), { key, value }]
        };

      case "seater":
      case "sleeper":
        return {
          ...conditions,
          seatSleeper: [...(conditions.seatSleeper || []), { key, value }]
        };

      // add new AND groups here

      default:
        return conditions;
    }
  }, {});
  return Object.values(filtersObject);
};

const filterData = (filters = []) => (el) =>
  mapfiltersToSets(filters).every((filterSet) =>
    filterSet.some(({ key, value }) => el[key] === value)
  );
```

Example:

```
// AC AND nonAC
data.filter(filterData([{ AC: "true" }, { nonAC: "true" }]))
```

Demo with extended dataset and unit tests. Good start to build from.

[image: Edit javascript-multiple-condition-filtering-with-array-of-conditions (forked)]

Comment: Everything gives me same output , as it returns the original array

Comment: @khristy_01 In my sandbox, or in your implementation of it? Can you share what you're doing in a *running* codesandbox? Oh, actually, I ***did*** normalize the data you provided in the array so booleans are *actually* booleans. Is this something you can do in your code or do you need to handle specifically stringified data?

Comment: I have added the original array with expected output on this repl.it ( [link](https://repl.it/@ajithfan/dynamicfilter) ), do check !

Comment: Please do check and let me know

Comment: @khristy_01 If you strictly compare against `"true"` in the condition callbacks then this solution correctly returns 9 and 4 elements for "AC || nonAC && sleeper" and "nonAC && sleeper" respectively. I.E. like `({ AC, nonAC }) => AC === 'true' || nonAC === 'true',`. This works but can be a bit tedious. Updated the sandbox and added a bit of explanation in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226805/discussion-between-khristy-01-and-drew-reese).

Comment: Kindly check the chat discussion!

Comment: Hey, check the chat discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but here is my attempt on creating some code that will check whether all conditions defined in `filterCond` are fulfilled.

I reformatted your `filterCond` into an easier to process array `fc`. After that the actual filtering becomes almost trivial: `fc.every(([k,v])=>a[k]==v )`. => every filter condition in the `fc`-array is checked whether it contains the same value as the corresponding property in one of the array `arr`'s element `a`.

```js
const arr = [
   {"AC": "false","nonAC": "true","sleeper":"true","availCatCard": "false"},
   {"AC": "true","nonAC": "false","sleeper":"false","availCatCard": "false"},
   {"AC": "true","nonAC": "true","sleeper":"false","availCatCard": "false"} ],
   filterCond = [{ AC: 'false'}, {nonAC: 'true'}, {sleeper: 'true'}],
   // create an array with uniuqe filter conditions:
   //           [["AC","false"],["nonAC","true"],["sleeper":"true"]]
   fc=Object.entries(filterCond.reduce((a,c)=>(Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v])=>a[k]=v),a),{}));
   
console.log(arr.filter(a=>fc.every(([k,v])=>a[k]==v ) ) )
```

For the purpose of this snippet I changed your filter condition since the original conditions would result in an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterArray = (array, conditions) => {
  const returnArr = []
  array.forEach(item => {
    let itemIsValid = true
    conditions.forEach(cond => {
      if(item[cond] !== "true") itemIsValid = false
    })
    if(itemIsValid)
      returnArr.push(item)
    else itemIsValid=true
  })
  return returnArr;
}
```

Then call: `filterArray(array, ["AC","nonAC"])` for `AC:true` & `nonAc:true`, and others likewise

Comment: How to do  if both AC & nonAC is true ?

Comment: Updated answer, please check

Comment: It gives empty array as output !

Comment: I have tried this in a [js editor](https://jsfiddle.net/fbzv32ua/) and it doesn't give an empty array as output